# TensorFlow Object Detection API - error = "This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already been[...]"

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, object-detection

I'm trying to get the TensorFlow Object Detection API on Windows. I use Python 3.6.5 (64bits).

After running the following program:

Here is the part of the code which generates the warning:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import six.moves.urllib as urllib
import sys
import tarfile
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile

from collections import defaultdict
from io import StringIO
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image



import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

from object_detection.utils import label_map_util

from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

I have this warning message :

```
    Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\leahj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\utils\visualization_utils.py", line 25
    import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')  # pylint: disable=multiple-statements
UserWarning: 
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: It's not clear from the question what `object_detection.utils` and `object_detection_tutorial.py` are or refer to. What you get is not an error, it's rather a warning that you (or some dependency) tried to use a different backend, but that it is impossible to use that selected backend because a different one has already been selected. The reason for this would lie inside the code you import - which is unknown here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I'm trying to run the object_detection_tutorial because I want to get the TensorFlow Object Detection API. I put the part of the code which generates the warning in the edit

Answer (score 0):

The line `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')` is [hardcoded](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/d1b91ba9b178c3e10cc7f8bd129606fba0fe6235/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py#L25) in `object_detection\utils\visualization_utils`. I don't know the reason for this; usually a package should allow the user to choose the backend.

Unless there is any other problem arising from the use of `object_detection` the easiest is probably to live with this warning.